# Calling devenv.exe for multiple .vdproj files

Tags: msbuild

I have a solution that has multiple vdproj files in it.
I have created an item group in my build.proj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
<SetupProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory\**\*.vdproj">
</SetupProjectFiles>
```

Now I want to call devenv.exe on each of those?

```
<Exec Command="devenv.exe %(SetupProjectFiles)"></Exec>
```

Doesn't work...anyone have any pointers please?

Comment: How exactly it 'doesnt work'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things worth double-checking. Check through this list and see the code snippet below for a working example.

1. Make sure the paths to vdproj files are correct. Try writing a message to the log for each file path, so you can verify which vdproj files are included.
2. Make sure the vdproj is included in the desired build configuration for the solution; if you are building a "Debug" configuration, make sure the vdproj is checked in the solution's build [Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the "Debug" config combination(s). You can set this globally or set it for each vdproj specified in the metadata of each `SetupProjectFiles` item (see snippet below for example of this).
3. Make sure to use the full devenv.exe path. You can use an environment variable to help out with this.
4. Make sure the [MSBuild Exec task syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) and [devenv.exe syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are correct, e.g., using the `/build` switch and using `&quot;` around paths with space characters.

---

**EDIT**: Corrected typos in code

---

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SetupProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.vdproj">
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  </SetupProjectFiles>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- VS110COMNTOOLS is for VS2012. VS100COMNTOOLS is for VS 2010. VS90COMNTOOLS is for VS2008 -->
  <DevEnvLocation>$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\devenv.exe</DevEnvLocation>
</PropertyGroup>

<Message Text="vdproj file:  %(SetupProjectFiles.FullPath)" />

<Exec Command="&quot;$(DevEnvLocation)&quot; &quot;%(SetupProjectFiles.FullPath)&quot; /build &quot;%(SetupProjectFiles.Configuration)&quot;" />
```

Comment: That's not working either. Our vdproj files are called blah.blah.vdproj or sometimes blah.blah.setup.vdproj

Comment: @Bernard, I found a missing parenthesis in my code above, so if you tried to use it without catching that issue, I can see why vdproj files would not have been found. Other than that, I'm not sure why the wildcard shown in your code or in my example would not work; they'll each find blah.blah.vdproj or blah.blah.setup.vdproj files. Are you getting an error? Have you done item 2 in my suggested answer to verify the vdproj files are being found?

Comment: @Bernard, I also found a typo in the Exec task...it is corrected now.